# Error handling in WordPress Data module selectors

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

When using the WordPress Data module ([`@wordpress/data`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/data), part of the [Gutenberg project](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg)), it's easy to fetch posts or other entities using `select('core').getEntityRecords` method. Here's [an example of Gutenberg using it internally](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/7e9aa078306096bb2e01db955dac562793a67186/packages/block-library/src/navigation-menu/edit.js#L94-L97).

However I can't find a way to **handle errors** in this scenario (e.g. a network error). Just as there is a method for checking if the request is in progress (`isResolving`), I'd expect one for error handling.

Some context:

- [`getEntityRecords`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/core-data/src/resolvers.js#L67-L79) method
- [`apiFetch`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/api-fetch/src/index.js) handler, used by `getEntityRecords` internally

Comment: To add to the issue, `isResolving` tend to stick even after the request has failed. For example if the server responds with an error code, there is an uncaught promise rejection in the console, but there is no way to catch that from a `withSelect` clause and the `isResolving` stays in true forever... Really hard to achieve reliable UX with such API.